# Split polygon based on line segment

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, line, streets

I am trying to split a street polygon based on the segment ID of the street, giving them the same segment_ID in the attribute table of the street lines. I did not use the line feature class to derive the polygon but instead used a polygon feature class that included the width of the roads (but was not divided into segments). [image: Street polygon and line feature classes]

I tried using the split tool, but it doesn't accept the street line segment as a feature.

Comment: Enable the advanced editor tool bar and select the polygons, try "Explode multi part feature"

Comment: That's a tricky one. (Explode won't work here BTW; not seeing any multipart features in the image). Why not recreate the buffers based on the line segments, just don't dissolve the buffer output. Presuming this is ArcGIS BTW. The catch here is that your buffers will have overlap but I think we can clean that up.

Comment: Try this [tool](http://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/split_by_attribute_tool.html), then loop through the individual result using spatial join to join the attributes together

Answer (score 1):

If the segment_ID is in the attribute table [Split Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=37AEB018-1422-2418-A036-CA6D9920F808) will split the original file based on the field you input.

Answer (score 1):

Create proximity polygons to segments, using Spatial analyst, raster to polygon. Intersect them with road polygons.

Answer (score 1):

1. create a cost allocation for each line segment based on segment_ID,
2. convert the cost allocation to polygons and
3. intersect each cost allocation polygon with you road polygons.